# DynamicListView Drag-n-Drop onDrop?

Tags: android, callback, drag-and-drop

I am trying out the https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations library to use in my program. Specifically, the Drag-n-Drop support.

While I managed to adjust the app to the DynamicListView (which was rather not difficult, thanks to the great lib provided by the author), I can't seem to understand how apply the changes to the persistent storage behind the data in the list - e.g., the sqlite database data.

Shouldn't there be a callback in the DynamicListView or in the ArrayAdapter that informs the app about the end of Drag-n-Drop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A callback would be nice, but it doesn't seem to be built into the library.

Taking a look at the source code you can see that the swapping takes place in the [`swapElements()`](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/blob/master/library/src/com/haarman/listviewanimations/view/DynamicListView.java#L501) function of [`DynamicListView.java`](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/blob/master/library/src/com/haarman/listviewanimations/view/DynamicListView.java). You can see that that it checks to see if the adapter provided to the list implements the `Swappable` interface, if so, its `swapItems()` function is called.

So simply all you need to do is implement that interface in your adapter and then provide it to the DynamicListView.

Comment: I saw the methods and at first thought of using them. But that would mean calling db.update on each swap, which seemed quite consuming to me.

Comment: Well you can implement the swapItems function however you please. You don't need to commit the changes right then if you don't want to. You could wait until onPause for example.

Comment: Kyle, thank you! Looks like you helped me get rid of my doubts, will try this approach :)

Answer (score 2):

Implement the DynamicListView.OnItemMovedListener and override onItemMoved(). Set this as the callback using DynamicListView.setOnItemMovedListener()